# Micronaut logging to cloudwatch in localstack without credentials

Tags: docker, amazon-cloudwatch, micronaut, micrometer, micronaut-micrometer

The idea is simple: write logs to cloudwatch in localstack from a Micronaut application.

So far any library requires credentials which I want to avoid. And typically I found no way to have localstack as target. And i assume credentials won't be required in AWS, using IAM roles.

Just saw [Micrometer](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-micrometer/latest/guide/#metricsAndReportersCloudWatch), but even there I can't find a way to define localstack as target.

Or does anyone have an idea how to send logs to cloudwatch in localstack without credentials? The Micronaut application runs also in Docker. But also [Amazon CloudWatch Logs logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/) seems not to be configurabe in Windows 10 regarding the target and asks for credentials (With Linux it seems to work).